# How to dump a stream for a defined amount of time on a schedule basis

Tags: linux, cron, service, dump, stream

I have a video stream from a video4linux device

/dev/dsp/adapter0/dvr0

I want to programmatically dump this stream for a predefined amount of time.

I think to schedule the jobs I might use cron and update it each day?

Any advice on how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Use a cron job to fire a script that calls tcpdump with the command-line options that are relevant to you. [The documentation for tcpdump](http://www.tcpdump.org/tcpdump_man.html) should help you with the specifics.

Comment: What does this have to do with network traffic?

Comment: If you're asking "what does tcpdump have to do with network traffic?", then I will also advise you to read the documentation as well. tcpdump is a network sniffer.

Comment: By "this" I mean the question.

Comment: So, did you mean to attach your comment to the question instead of my answer? I see "dump" and "stream" and I assumed it was a question related to the network traffic that happened to be video. I might be off-base. Who knows - Fabrizio never came back to this site, it appears.